# Laravel + phpunit - view() not working in unit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

So I have an XML "view" I want to test using mocked data in php unit. I basically have this:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    //output is an array of mocked data, assume that it's populated
    //"homepage" is a blade template that outputs xml
    $this->xml = view("homepage", $this->output)->render();
}
```

then I have a suite of tests, for example this one, that verifies that the xml contains what it should:

```
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testXMLHasTemplate()
{
    $this->assertRegexp('/<template>/', $this->xml);
}
```

However, when I run this very basic test I get the following errors:

> Fatal error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw
>   an exception, caught ErrorException: syntax error, unexpected
>   'version' (T_STRING) (View:
>   /Users/171599/Documents/php_projects/vmdisks/dlarvarwww/v4api/html/resources/views/homepage.blade.php)
>   in
>   /Users/171599/Documents/php_projects/vmdisks/dlarvarwww/v4api/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/Assert.php
>   on line 0

This same view method works just fine when used from a controller. But it seems to not work from **phpunit**. Is there a way to generate a view within phpunit like you would within a controller?

edit: here is my blade "view" for reference. It's all XML:

homepage.blade.php:

```
{!! "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>" !!}
<homepage template="{{ $template }}">
    @foreach ($entities as $entity) 
        @if ($entity["type"] == 'Section') 
            @include('partials.section', ["section" => $entity])
        @elseif ($entity["type"] == 'SectionGroup')
            <sectiongroup>
                @each('partials.section', $entity['sections'], 'section')
            </sectiongroup>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <user id="{{ $user["user_id"] }}" email="{{ $user["email"] }}" listening_time="{{ $user["listening_time"] }}"/>
</homepage>
```

section.blade.php:

```
<section name="{{ $section['name'] }}" type="{{ $section["section_type"] }}">
    @foreach ($section["items"] as $item)
        @switch($item["type"])
            @case("feed")
                <feed id="{{$item["id"]}}" name="{{$item["description"]}}" imageURL="{{ $item["imageURL"] }}">
                    @include("partials.episode", ["episode" => $item["latest_episode"] ])
                </feed>
            @break
            @case("episode")
                @include("partials.episode", ["episode" => $item])
            @break
            @case("shortcut")
                <shortcut id="{{ $item['id'] }}" name="{{ $item['name'] }}" />
            @break
        @endswitch
    @endforeach
</section>
```

Comment: why do you have views in your unit test using a backend language, sound very wrong

Comment: Because the "view" is just some xml output that I want to test. It's not really an html view,  so I don't see the problem?

Comment: then why not read the file directly, instead of using view method, its clearly meant for blade views

Comment: because i'm using blade syntax in there to process the data in $output to generate the xml. i can't just "read" the file....

Comment: This is incorrect the code is trying to put a view containing PHP code into a variable, framework is being misued. perhaps if you share the xml I can guide you more

Comment: Ok I added the views to the question. I'm thinking it might be better to make this a feature test and to hit an endpoint with the xml in question and then testing the response that way. additionally I'm using ->render() so it should output the raw xml to the variable in theory

Comment: I feel like you should write a helper that can take some input and outputs the xml.
I also recommend using a PHP xml library to build your xml. This way you can unit test that helper without messing with views.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you there is an error in `views/homepage.blade.php` - the string `version` is present when it is not expected to be. Look into what is happening in that file.

Comment: that's not it, this same method works fine in a controller. looking at the cached views, it looks like the view generated by phpunit contains invalid php compared to the one generated by a controller. so this is a bug with laravel and phpunit.

Comment: Try changing the part of the view you've escaped with Blade with regular PHP tags - `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' ?>`

Comment: that does seem to fix the error about version being undefined, however for some reason view() and View::make() aren't translating the foreach, if, and switch blade statements into valid php